# Render html element present inside jquery autocomplete data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I am making use of jQuery autocomplete with remote data source. Remote data contains HTML tags. Sample data is of form:

```
[
  "ABC <span>XYZ</span>",
  "PQR <span>LMN</span>",

];
```

Autocomplete dropdown contain output like

`ABC <span>XYZ</span>
 PQR <span>LMN</span>`

I want HTML tags to get render and dropdown to show output like

`ABC XYZ
 PQR LMN`

http://jsfiddle.net/ac112jmx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it using [Custom Display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) use `.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem` method.

[instance()](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-instance)

> Retrieves the autocomplete's instance object. If the element does not have an associated instance, `undefined` is returned.

[_renderItem( ul, item )](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem)

> Method that controls the creation of each option in the widget's menu. The method must create a new `<li>` element, append it to the menu, and return it.

*Code*

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item);
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/12qh3nz4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parseHTML(str)`

```
var dropdown = $.parseHTML('ABC <span>XYZ</span>');
```

Check the following example:

```js
$('#wrp').html($.parseHTML('This is a <b>Bold text</b>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="wrp"></span>
```